# shipping description CSS error woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, aster

I am having an issue with adding a description to the shipping method
I used this snippet to add description

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'action_after_shipping_rate', 20, 2 );
function action_after_shipping_rate ( $method, $index ) {
    if( 'flat_rate:12' === $method->id ) {
        echo __("<p style=''>(موالح،المعبيلة،الحيل،عبري،نزوى،صحار،السويق،بركاء،المصنعة،ابراء،صور،هيما،صلالة،جعلان بني بوعلي،سناو،الكامل،روي)</p>");
    }
}
```

but sadly it looks like this
[with snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AlX7.png) ,
without it, it looks like this "how it should look like"
[without snippet (normal look)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF78D.png)

Comment: You can use custom CSS after adding the element. Or you can add a fixed width to the element.

Comment: how do I do this? if possiable

Comment: like what to write to fix it? i know how to add custom css - https://boncoffee.store

Comment: For checking it we need the website url